# Cocos2d Parallax Loop

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, parallax

I've searched all of the forums and cannot find a working solution to get my parallax layer to loop. YES - I've tried all of the tutorials, includine the Space shooter by Ray Wenderlich but I'm struggling. Here's the code:

```
CCParallaxNode *parallax = [CCParallaxNode node];

// My Parallax Layer
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
CCSprite *midground = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"trees.png"];
midground.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);

[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_Default];
[parallax addChild:midground z:-9 parallaxRatio:ccp(1.4f, 1.4f) positionOffset:ccp(0,0)];

//Please loop once off screen
```

The image is 960x640 and i would like it to update and loop once it leaves the page. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple solution:

http://www.gomonkey.it/2012/02/cocos2d-scorrimento-del-background/

You have need 2 images